# Grub menu (entry) missing on system with many hard disks

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, kubuntu

I must admit, I have quite a mess with all my hard disks. I have 4 internal ones, 3 of which each with a particular Ubuntu on it.

[image: all my disks]

It worked fine, but now I can't boot the Kubuntu I am actually using - it is the one highlighted in the screenshot. I cant find it anywhere in the Grub menu.  As a matter of fact, I don't even know, from which of my 4 hard disks the GRUB-Menu is loaded. Embarrassing, I know.

So, how can I get the Kubuntu on /dev/nvme0n1p1 to re-appear in the Grub Menu??

Here's a screenshot of the Boot Options in the BIOS:

[image]
Help! I need my daily Kubuntu to get back to working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in my case was quite simple: The GRUB-Menu at startup of my system at sometime just renamed and repositioned every Ubuntu I have on my Computer. This obviously happened after a major Kernel update.

So, just make sure whether GRUB unknowingly "just" renamed and/or repositioned the entry in GRUB you're looking for.